# Internal MediaWiki sends emails to old users who were watching articles

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

We run an internal MediaWiki Wiki for knowledge share and documentation. We have noticed some pages that are Watched by some users include old users that have left our employ but are still getting the emails when changes are made to those articles.

Please advise how we can remove those users and review any other pages that are watched by non existing users?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best approach is to set [`$wgBlockDisablesLogin`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgBlockDisablesLogin) and indefinitely block users when they leave. That flag will also lock blocked user accounts down in a number of other ways than preventing login, including not sending them any emails.

Other possible approaches include "deleting" users with the [UserMerge](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UserMerge) extension, invalidating their emails (e.g. with the [`resetUserEmail.php`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ResetUserEmail.php) maintenance script) or manually control who gets watchlist notifications via the [SendWatchlistEmailNotification](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/SendWatchlistEmailNotification) hook.